# Google login in android webview stuck in a page where it prompts "One Moment Please" and a loading Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-webview, google-signin

I have a webview in my android app which loads a website which has a google login button. When login button is pressed it opens a browser and after signing in it gets stuck in a page which prompts "One moment please". Why is it getting stuck in that page and not redirecting to the app?

Comment: Can anyone answer this ? I am also sucked at the same point.

Comment: @AbhaySingh I couldnot do it either. I switched to Chrome custom tab. Its a better workaround. Here is the [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Answer (score 3):

First of all use this setting for your webview :

```
WebView vistaWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
vistaWeb.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient(this));
vistaWeb.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient(this));
vistaWeb.clearCache(true);
vistaWeb.clearHistory();
vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
vistaWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Then if that wasn't quit the answer, use a library from github webview library or use Chrome custom tab.

Comment: where is the definition of the customechromeclient and customwebclient classes?

Comment: those are custom made classes (there are some defaults in the library too). but those two lines of client arent necessary.